# TFS to GIT Migration looking for roles and responsibilities best practices

Tags: git, tfs, bitbucket-server

Migrating from TFS to GIT, STASH. Read there is a concept of gatekeeper who has to review the code and take a call on merging with the main branch. Looking for the  best practice on what developers are supposed to do, what leads are supposed to do, what administrators roles & responsibilities etc., while using these products.

Comment: By "Stash", do you mean Atlassian Stash?

Comment: @Chris Yes i meant altassian Stash

Comment: What kind of project? Are you accepting 3rd party commits? Are all contributors trusted? These are all questions that influence how you'd use Git.

Comment: Some scenario's are explained here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

Comment: Other workflows you might want to investigate:https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Answer (score 1):

In stash, you can lock down branches to specific persons(gatekeepers).

For the branches that are handled by gatekeepers, you create a ***pull*** request from your source branch and only the gatekeepers have the privilege to merge the branch.

Ideally you have a ***develop*/*master*** branch which is locked down to developers. Developers create ***feature*** branches and work on these feature branches. Once they are done with feature branches, they create pull requests **from feature** branches **to develop/master** branch.

In case you have a medium to large team and work on more than a single release at a time, I suggest you use **gitFlow**